# Add text from c# code to a gridview label

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, label, itemtemplate

I need to add an specific text in an itemtemplate on a gridview...

right now I have this in my gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="Total" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text='<%#Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Total")), 2).ToString("C") + " M.N."%>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

in the part where it says

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text='<%#Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Total")), 2).ToString("C") + " M.N."%>'>
```

I made an specific text, but it will always be the same text (well except in the Eval of course)... But I need to get the format I need from this method.

```
public static string GetFormatoMoneda(decimal decCantidad)
{
    //Get data from currency (Dollars, Pesos, Euros, etc.)
    DataRow dr = ConexionBD.GetInstanciaConexionBD().GetTipoDeMonedaPrincipal((int)HttpContext.Current.Session["Grupo"]);

    return dr["Signo"] + Math.Round(decCantidad, 2).ToString("C").Substring(1) + " " + dr["Abreviatura"];
}
```

I use this method to get a specific string and use it on labels (I assign it on code on the cs file)..
But in this case... I have to insert that text on the column of a gridview...

How can I get that string value and insert it on a label inside of a templatefield/itemtemplate??

Comment: Does Text='<%#GetFormatoMoneda(Eval("Total"))%>' work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ...

```
Text='<%#Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Total")), 2).ToString("C") + " M.N."%>'
```

...use

```
Text='<%#GetFormatoMoneda(Eval("Total"))%>'
```

However, this assumes that GetFormatoMoneda is in the same class as the web form.  If not, then you need to include the class name, e.g.

```
Text='<%#MyClass.GetFormatoMoneda(Eval("Total"))%>'
```

Then you either need to make a change to GetFormatoMoneda to use an object type parameter, e.g.

```
public static string GetFormatoMoneda(object objCantidad)
{
    var decCantidad = Convert.ToDecimal(decCantidad);

    //Get data from currency (Dollars, Pesos, Euros, etc.)
    DataRow dr = ConexionBD.GetInstanciaConexionBD().GetTipoDeMonedaPrincipal((int)HttpContext.Current.Session["Grupo"]);

    return dr["Signo"] + Math.Round(decCantidad, 2).ToString("C").Substring(1) + " " + dr["Abreviatura"];
}
```

or use another method with an object parameter and call GetFormatoMoneda(decimal), passing in the correct value, such as

```
protected string CorrectFormat(object obj)
{
    return GetFormatoMoneda(Convert.ToDecimal(obj));
}
```

in which case you would use

```
Text='<%#CorrectFormat(Eval("Total"))%>'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it programmatically, this would work:

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvGrid_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    //Generate fake data
    var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 20);

    //Give the data to the grid
    gvGrid.DataSource = data;
    gvGrid.DataBind();
  }
}

protected void gvGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    //Find the control
    var lblTotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");

    //Get the data for this row
    var data = (int)e.Row.DataItem;

    //Display the data
    lblTotal.Text = data.ToString();
  }
}
```