# ASP.NET how to add text to label in gridview using a class in C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, gridview, itemtemplate

I need to know how can I use a class to get a string and add it to a label inside an itemtemplate in agridview...

I previously posted this question:
[Add text from c# code to a gridview label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663668/add-text-from-c-sharp-code-to-a-gridview-label)

I got an answer where I noticed I get the string from a class in a cs file...
to be more specific, here's my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace ClientesPagos
{
    public class Funciones
    {
        public static string GetFormatoMoneda(decimal decCantidad)
        {
            DataRow dr = ConexionBD.GetInstanciaConexionBD().GetTipoDeMonedaPrincipal((int)HttpContext.Current.Session["Grupo"]);
            return dr["Signo"] + Math.Round(decCantidad, 2).ToString("C").Substring(1) + " " + dr["Abreviatura"];
        }
    }
}
```

from one of the suggestions, I tried to use this:

```
Text='<%#Funciones.GetFormatoMoneda(Eval("Total"))%>'
```

Did not work...

then I tried something that I don't want to do, but just for testing I tried it. My gridview is in a file called Ventas.aspx... so I added that same class on Ventas.aspx.cs and then I switch the text to:

```
Text='<%#GetFormatoMoneda(Eval("Total"))%>'
```

also, I tried switching in GetFormatoMoneda(decimal decCantidad) to GetFormatoMoneda(object objCantidad), with no success at all...

Do you know a way to fix this? or if you could provide a different answer on the other question on the link above?

Comment: any errors ? what is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
    Text='<%# Eval(Funciones.GetFormatoMoneda(1.0))%>'
```

Just replace the `1.0` I have written inside the function call `GetFormatoMoneda`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately it did not work that way..
I once again placed the method in Ventas.aspx.cs
and used this
Text='<%#GetFormatoMoneda(Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Total")))%>
AND IT WORKED...

however, if I use
Text='<%#Funciones.GetFormatoMoneda(Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Total")))%>
It doesn't work because the class Funciones does not exist in that context

Comment: Just append the Namespace behind it so it reads `    Text='<%#Eval(ClientesPagos.Funciones.GetFormatoMoneda(1.0))%>'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gridview.rowdatabound event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) to manipulate grid row in the code behind.